# how to beautify source code in html/jsp page while running?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, syntax-highlighting

I have designed a web page that contain some java source code. I have put all those code in block. Its come nice but I want to make it more beautify. Like its seems like its a java code. Here is my page code. (you make take a reference from http://www.concretepage.com/freemarker/freemarker-templateloader-with-multitemplateloader-example )

Is there any online library or plugin of JS that beautify code?
[image: Output of my page]

```
   <body>
 <div class="container">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
    <div class="row">
           <h2>Heading</h2>
        <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>

        <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>
        <pre><code>
  import java.util.Scanner;

  public class CalTest {

  public static void main(String args[]) {
  int a, b;
 float c;
 System.out.println("Enter the First No: ");
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
 a = sc.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter the Second No: ");
b = sc.nextInt();
c = a + b;
 System.out.println("Total =" + c);
  }
   }

             </code></pre>


    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try this, http://www.tutorialspoint.com/online_html_formatter.htm

Answer (score 1):

Try with https://highlightjs.org/, and you can literally find all you need by typing [javascript library for syntax highlighting](https://www.google.com.mx/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=javascript%20library%20for%20syntax%20highlighting) on a Google search.

Answer (score 1):

There are some libraries like for example https://highlightjs.org
this one need only to place your code into `<pre><code>` tags and run `hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();` so it seems pretty easy to use.